# Why is my sound cutting out in my WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio-player

So this is strange...in my C#, WPF app, I have a button that, when clicked, plays a short audio clip that acts as help text. About 50% of the time it works beautifully...the other 50% it gets cut off and I can't figure out why. Even the point at which it is being cut off varies.

I thought that, maybe, the code was going out of scope or something and then stopping so I put it in another thread...that didn't work at all...so now I am not sure what to do.

Here is the code of my button click event.

```
try
{
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaPath"], Global.Language);
    path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "visitorTypes.mp3");

    if (Global.PlaySound)
    {
        string p = path.ToString();
        MediaPlayer mplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mplayer.Open(new Uri(p, UriKind.Absolute));
        mplayer.Play();
    }

    //a bunch of other code

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Util.HandleError(ex);
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be that *mplayer* is being garbage collected because it has local scope. Try making the media player object a member variable of a class that has application lifetime.

Comment: That worked! I am a bit embarrassed I didn't think of that. Your solution is essentially what I was trying to do with a separate thread, but yours, of course, actually did something. 

Thanks!